# Java: Compiling Error Concerning Breaks

Tags: java

I am a freshman in college, currently in my first semester of my Computer Programming course; we have started by working with pseudo code and Java simultaneously.

We had been tasked with the creation of a java application that totals, and creates an average, of a series of numbers that have been input by the user. The user may input as many numbers as they wish until the number 0 is input, in which case the program outputs the total and the average, and then prompts the user to start over or exit the program.

I accomplished this task using two while loops, one of which is nested. When attempting to break the nested loop, however, I receive the error "Error: break outside switch or loop". Afterwards, I spent much time browsing this forum looking for answers and information concerning the problem, but none seemed relevant to my problem, and fixes did not work. Among the list was using labeled breaks and correcting curly brackets; because these did not seem to work, I'm convinced the problem lies deeper in the code.

Because my course is online, it is very difficult to communicate with the professor or other students in a timely manner, which is why I have turned to this community!

Below I will attach the pseudo code that the professor wanted us to base our application off of.

```
Start
Declarations
Num sumTotal = 0  // Initialize for clarity
Num numEntered
Num averageNum
Num loopCounter
Num answer
String endProgram = “Y” // Initialize so that outer loop will work
    End declarations
// Greet the user
Output “Welcome to our calculator. “
Output “Enter as many numbers as you want.”
Output “When you are done entering numbers, enter 0 (zero) to display the sum.”
Output “Do you want to start the calculator? (Y/N): “  // Let the user   decide to start
input endProgram
// Note: if the user enters anything but Y or y, the loop will not execute. 
While endProgram <> “Y” OR endProgram <> “y”  // Allows the user to perform multiple calculations
//Enter the first number (sentinel value)
Output “Please enter your first number.”
Input numEntered
While numEntered <> 0  // Allows the user to enter numbers for the current calculation
    Output “You entered the number “ + numEntered  // echo input
    sumTotal = sumTotal + numEntered  // Add number entered to total
        loopCounter++ // Increment the number of entries
Output “Please enter the next number”
Input numEntered  // If 0, the loop will end here
endWhile // the nested inner loop code stops here
// Output section
Output “The total numbers entered is: “ + loopCounter
Output “The total of the numbers entered is: “ + sumTotal
Output “The average of the numbers entered is: “ + averageNum
Output “Would you like to do a new set of calculations? Y/N
Input endProgram
    End While // End outer While statement when endProgram = Y
    Output “Thank you for using the calculator. The program will now end.”      
Stop // Stop the program
```

Below I will attach my Java code

```
/* Module 4 Assignment 1 Part 1
* Aaron Field
* Submitted March 26, 2016
* Using DrJava */

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Calculator {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //variable declarations
    int numEntered;
    int sumTotal = 0;
    int averageNum = sumTotal / numEntered;
    int loopCounter;
    String endProgram = "Y";
    //end declarations

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Totaling Calculator");
    System.out.println("This program will accept integer inputs until 0 is entered" + '\n' + "When 0 is entered, a sum and an average will be displayed.");

endProgram = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                            "Do you want to start the calculator? (Y/N): ");

while(endProgram != "Y" || endProgram != "y"); {
        numEntered = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                    "Please enter your first number."));
        while(numEntered != 0); {
          System.out.println("You entered the number " + numEntered);
                               sumTotal = sumTotal + numEntered;
                               loopCounter++;
                             numEntered = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                                                      "Please enter the next number")); 
                             break;}


        System.out.println("The total numbers entered is: " + loopCounter + '\n' + "The total of the numbers entered is: " + sumTotal + '\n' + "The average of the numbers entered is: " + averageNum);

        endProgram = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                                 "Would you like to do a new set of calculations? (Y/N): ");
        break;
}

System.out.println("Thank you for using the calculator. The program will now end.");
                   }
}
```

I understand the code may be sloppy or strange, but I've only been working with Java for since mid-February, so excuse any sloppy formatting or incorrect use of code.

To my untrained eyes, the break statements seem to be within the loops; I am rather confused as to why my compiler would suggest they aren't. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You are providing `break` statement without any condition.

Comment: `"...so excuse any sloppy formatting..."` -- rather than post this, why not simply learn how to format your code correctly, and then post well-formatted code? It's not that hard to learn, and it is effort that **you** should make when asking volunteers to help you, no?

Comment: Why are you even using break here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolons after your while statements.

Example: change

```
while(endProgram != "Y" || endProgram != “y”); {
//...
}
```

to

```
while(endProgram != "Y" || endProgram != “y”) {
//...
}
```

A while statement followed by a semicolon is actually interpreted as this

```
while(condition) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

**while(...);** it's a bad practice :P. Your break commands are in fact all outside the while loops.